# Cannot Read css file when loading html in Play framework java-play

Tags: java, html, css, playframework

when using java-play project with play framework and want to add css to the html file, only html displayed, what am i doing wrong?

the ROUTES:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET  /                         controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="/screens/loginForm/Login.html")
GET  /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

the html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at('screens/loginForm/Login.css')">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-1">
        <p class="field">
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username or email">
            <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>
        </p>
        <p class="field">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <i class="icon-lock icon-large"></i>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is "screens/loginForm/Login.css" in the "public" folder ?

Comment: Because you are overriding the Assets route the second route is never  being used. You should remove the first route and just call `http://localhost/assets/screens/loginForm/Login.html`